# Undo Lubuntu install?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I had 13.04 running fine although a bit slow, so I did

`sudo apt-get install lubuntu`

then restarted the computer

next, lubuntu opened, but it was terrible. The dock wasn't there, alt+tab and other window-control commands didn't work, and I couldn't search through the system for programs to open as I could before.

Surely all this can't be so difficult to reverse? All I did was one command.

Comment: `sudo apt-get remove lubuntu` is how you remove normal packages

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about removing packages on Ubuntu. You may be able to get help on [ubuntu.se] 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove lubuntu
```

Now you must switch your desktop environment. If you want ubuntu default desktop environment

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure ubuntu-desktop
```

Or if you have KDE

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure kubuntu-desktop
```

It's better to try dpkg-reconfigure before package removing.